# H2O GLM function not recognizing data passed in as H2OFrame

Tags: python, h2o

I don't understand why I'm getting the error below. I've imported csv data as an h2oFrame. It's clearly an h2oFrame since I can perform methods such as describe() and such. But, when I pass it in to the glm function, I'm getting the rror saying that it's not the proper datatype. Why is this occurring?

```
dat = h2o.import_files(data_dir)
glm_normal = H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator(family='gaussian') 
glm_normal.train(x=x, y=y, train_frame=dat)
```

**Error:** 
H2OTypeError: Argument `training_frame` should be an H2OFrame, got NoneType None

Answer (score 3):

The the problem is that you typed `train_frame` as the argument instead of `training_frame` (which defaults to `None`).

Comment: ughh god... I hate when a silly misreading happens. Thanks for the quick spot.